# Swift Some Lottie Animations Distorted

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I am using Lottie in my iOS app, and have changed the colors of all animations to fit my color palatte. All animations are json file that i download directly from the lottie editor. The lottie editor shows an animation working, but the result is distorted for some and fine for others, using the same method. Is there something wrong with the JSON that i can fix?

```
    func expandModal() {
        if state != .contracted {
            return
        }
        dismissMe = false
        contractedFrame = self.frame
        solutionLabel.alpha = 0
        state = .gettingBigger
        let animation = Animation.named(name)
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.loopMode = .loop
        animationView.frame = leftArrow.frame
        leftArrow.alpha = 0
        addSubview(animationView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [self] in
            frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)
            center = self.superview!.center
            layer.cornerRadius = 10
            leftArrow.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: modalType == .Points ? 100 : 150, height: modalType == .Points ? 100 : 150)
            leftArrow.center.x = frame.width / 2
            animationView.frame = leftArrow.frame
            titleLabel.alpha = 1
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
            titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 24*kWidthFactor, y: leftArrow.frame.maxY + 24 * kHeightFactor, width: self.frame.width - 48 * kWidthFactor, height: 1000)
            titleLabel.font = sfUITextBold(fontSize: 24 * kHeightFactor)
            titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
            titleLabel.sizeToFit()
            titleLabel.center.x = self.frame.width / 2
            addSubview(titleLabel)
                        
            descriptionLabel.alpha = 1
            descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            descriptionLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 24*kWidthFactor, y: titleLabel.frame.maxY + 12 * kHeightFactor, width: self.frame.width - 48 * kWidthFactor, height: 1000)
            descriptionLabel.text = descriptionString
            descriptionLabel.font = sfUITextRegular(fontSize: 18 * kHeightFactor)
            descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
            addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        } completion: { [self] _ in
            self.state = .expanded
            animationView.play()
        }
    }
```

Pathfinder [json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlpP-9WFtkwbSkt_xajBFQcwDfrZBcfI/view?usp=sharing) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ULWx.png) [editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOhzT.jpg)

Architect [json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jTKKDHw808O0aAS4q8fmr8xQoaguTqTr/view?usp=sharing) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ZQ3.png)

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81N9.jpg) of app

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, did you ever figure out the issue or a fix?

Comment: I found that using animations straight from Lottie website wouldn’t get distorted. Using iconScout were getting distorted